# Wrong results in Google spreadsheets Lookup functions (vlookup, hlookup, match)

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, gs-vlookup

The following spreadsheet demonstrates a very odd behaviour of Google Spreadsheets Lookup functions. I've used these functions many times without any problem. Can anyone confirm it happens on their side as well?

Example doc: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16lRQ72K28CtObY_ChzpNQUVTl_EgbjEyRcpP5QOZKzE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @pnuts it looks like a bug to me, but just in case it's the expected behaviour, I'd like Excel experts to notice this question.

Comment: Just add `FALSE` in the optional parameter i.e. `=VLOOKUP(A2,A1:E13,5,FALSE)`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

By Default `VLOOKUP` does approximate matches.  @Pnuts explained that the desired result is not being returned in every case because the the search is binary.

Excels optional parameter for [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) is called **range_lookup** and quote:

> **range_lookup** Optional. A logical value that specifies whether you
>   want VLOOKUP to find an exact match or an approximate match:
>
> - If range_lookup is either TRUE or is omitted, an exact or approximate
>     match is returned. If an exact match is not found, the next largest
>     value that is less than lookup_value is returned.
> - IMPORTANT   If range_lookup is either TRUE or is omitted, the values
>     in the first column of table_array must be placed in ascending sort
>     order; otherwise, VLOOKUP might not return the correct value.
> - For more information, see Sort data in a range or table.
> - If range_lookup is FALSE, the values in the first column of
>     table_array do not need to be sorted.
> - If the range_lookup argument is FALSE, VLOOKUP will find only an exact
>     match. If there are two or more values in the first column of
>     table_array that match the lookup_value, the first value found is
>     used. If an exact match is not found, the error value #N/A is
>     returned.

Google's optional parameter for [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) is called **is_sorted** and quote:

> **is_sorted** - [OPTIONAL - TRUE by default] - Indicates whether the
>   column to be searched (the first column of the specified range) is
>   sorted.
>
> - If is_sorted is TRUE or omitted, the nearest match (less than or equal
>     to the search key) is returned. If all values in the search column are
>     greater than the search key, #N/A is returned.
> - If is_sorted is set to TRUE or omitted, and the first column of the
>     range is not in sorted order, an incorrect value might be returned.
> - If is_sorted is FALSE, only an exact match is returned. If there are
>     multiple matching values, the content of the cell corresponding to the
>     first value found is returned, and #N/A is returned if no such value
>     is found.

If you need **exact** matching with `VLOOKUP` just add `FALSE` in the optional parameter to force the lookup of exact matching.  If you are using the `MATCH` then add a 0.

So the formulas for your spreadsheet should look like:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,A1:E13,5,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP("n1-standard-2",A1:E13,5,FALSE)
=MATCH(A2,A1:A13,0)
=MATCH("n1-standard-2",A1:A13,0)
=HLOOKUP(A1,A1:E13,5,FALSE)
=HLOOKUP("n1-standard-1",A1:E13,5,FALSE)
```

Comment: I believe they should have named it `nearest_match` instead of `is_sorted`.